# How to convert number value to string in SCSS

Tags: sass

I have a variable in SCSS. This variable could be a number `500` or a string `italic`, based on users input.

With Webpack I got an Error

> @if str-index($style, "italic") {
> ^
> Argument `$string` of `str-index($string, $substring)` must be a string

**How can I convert the number into a string in SCSS/SASS?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the same question and found a solution. You have to wrap the number in `#{}` to use the [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation).

Here is a demo function:

```
@function transform-number-to-string($value) {
  @if type-of($value)=='number' {
    @return #{$value};
  }
  @else if type-of($value)=='string' {
    @return $value;
  }
  @else {
    @error 'Input #{$value} is no number or string';
  }
}
```

More info:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation